# Добавление HTML через jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Есть такой код:

```
    <td>
       <div class="cover" data-id="<?echo $edit_works['id'];?>">
       <img src="<?echo base_url()?><?echo $edit_works['cover']?>" style="float: left;"/>
        <p class="btn-del" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="<?echo base_url()?>images/icon/delete_icon.png" width="20px"/></p>
    <div>
   </td>
```

По клику на `<p>` у меня тег `<div>` сворачивается и удаляется. Вот так:

```
$thisItem.slideUp(300,function(){
                      $thisItem.remove();
                  });
```

AJAX возвращает некий HTML код. Так вот, как мне вставить его после удаления в `<td>`?
Чтобы было типа того:

```
<td>
<p>Мой код вставленны jquery. Дива больше нет.</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сразу же нашел ответ, 20 минут лазил, нигде не мог найти, сразу же нашел.
 Нужно `<td>` добавить `id` и добавлять через `append();`.

Answer (score 0):

А можно и не через `append()`:

```
$('#' + tdID).html('Код, вставляемый аяксом...');
```

:)